# How to run function through a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dataframe

```
  teamname=print(prem['HomeTeam'].unique())

  ['Liverpool' 'West Ham' 'Bournemouth' 'Burnley' 'Crystal Palace' 'Watford' 'Tottenham' 'Leicester' 
  'Newcastle' 'Man United' 'Arsenal' 'Aston Villa' 'Brighton' 'Everton' 'Norwich' 'Southampton' 'Man 
   City' 'Sheffield United' 'Chelsea' 'Wolves']

   def TeamsPointsDict(df,teamname):
       team_name = teamname 
       num_points = df.loc[prem['HomeTeam'] == teamname, 'HP'].sum() + df.loc[prem['AwayTeam']==teamname, 'AP'].sum()
       d=dict()
       d[team_name]= num_points
       return d



       print(TeamsPointsDict(df,'Man City'))

       {'Man City': 57}
```

So I have created the list teamname above and then create a function that returns a dictionary with one name from the list teamname and the amount of points they have. Now, I am wondering how I would be able to run the function through the entire list of teamname and print all the teams and their respective points. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully get what's happening in your code but,

Would this do what you want? If not comment on why not and I will add to  the answer

```
for team in ARRAY_OF_TEAMS:
    print(TeamsPointsDict(df, team));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your operation is essentially adding two sum aggregations, consider `pandas.groupby` with a `join` requiring no `for` loop:

```
def TeamsPointsDict(df, teamname):
    agg_df = (df.groupby(['HomeTeam'])['HP'].sum()
                .to_frame()
                .query("HomeTeam == @teamname")
                .join(df.groupby(['AwayTeam'])['AP'].sum())
                .sum(axis=1)
             )

    return agg_df.to_dict()

print(TeamsPointsDict(df, 'Man City'))
```

---

To demonstrate with random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

teams = ['Liverpool', 'West Ham', 'Bournemouth', 'Burnley', 'Crystal Palace', 
         'Watford', 'Tottenham', 'Leicester', 'Newcastle', 'Man United', 
         'Arsenal', 'Aston Villa', 'Brighton', 'Everton', 'Norwich', 
         'Southampton', 'Man City', 'Sheffield United', 'Chelsea', 'Wolves']

### DATA BUILD
np.random.seed(41320)
random_df = pd.DataFrame({'HomeTeam': np.random.choice(teams, 500),
                          'HP': np.random.randint(1, 10, 500),
                          'AwayTeam': np.random.choice(teams, 500),
                          'AP': np.random.randint(1, 10, 500)})

def TeamsPointsDict(df, teamname):
    agg_df = (df.groupby(['HomeTeam'])['HP'].sum()
                .to_frame()
                .query("HomeTeam == @teamname")
                .join(df.groupby(['AwayTeam'])['AP'].sum())
                .sum(axis=1)
             )

    return agg_df.to_dict()


print(TeamsPointsDict(random_df, 'Man City'))
# {'Man City': 238}
```

Comment: Hi this does work but the question is telling me to write a function that takes inputs and returns a dictionary

Comment: See edit wrapping process in a function. Remove `.query()` to return a dictionary of all teams. But it sounds like you are answering a coursework assignment and not your own analysis.

Comment: Yh it didn't work so that i could run the function through a list so that it printed it for all teams

Comment: Oh wait parfait I have realised I have been an idiot and just not looked at your code properly I am so sorry!